Is there a known algorithm for problems similar to but different from what Newton's identities can solve?
Suppose $a$ numbers $z_i$ and $b$ numbers $p_i$.
All these $a+b$ numbers are unknown, but, for a given exponent, the difference of the sums of their powers is known : the value of $d_1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^az_i-\sum\limits_{i=1}^bp_i$ is known, the value of $d_2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^az_i^2-\sum\limits_{i=1}^bp_i^2$ is known, ..., and, more generally, we know all the values of $d_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^az_i^n-\sum\limits_{i=1}^bp_i^n$ for any $n$, as well as the values of $a$ and $b$.
The question is "how to obtain $s_1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^az_i+\sum\limits_{i=1}^bp_i$ ?"
My observations (inspired by Newton-Girard-Waring's identities) led me to an algorithm using the $n=a+b$ first values of $d$, but I'm unable to prove it, and I'm wondering if it is a known problem since it has a nice application when evaluating the zeroes and the poles of a rational function with  the argument principle.
First, let's define a useful sequence:
Definition 1 :
$$
k_n=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cl}
1 & \mathrm{when}\quad n=0\\
\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}k_{n-i} }{n} & \mathrm{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The first step of the algorithm is based on the following property,
when $a=1$, that I can't prove either:
Theorem 1 : When $a=1$ (that is $d_n=z_1^n-\sum\limits_{i=1}^bp_i^n$), then $k_{b+1}=z_1k_b.$
You can verify by hand (or with Coq) on the first values of $b$. For instance, with $b=2$, we have
$$d_1=z_1-p_1-p_2,$$
$$d_2=z_1^2-p_1^2-p_2^2,$$
$$d_3=z_1^3-p_1^3-p_2^3 $$ and
$$k_0=1$$
$$k_1=\frac{d_1k_0}{1}=z_1-p_1-p_2$$
$$k_2=\frac{d_1k_1+d_2k_0}{2}=(z_1-p_1)(z_1-p_2)$$ and indeed
$$k_3=\frac{d_1k_2+d_2k_1+d_3k_0}{3}=z_1k_2. (\mathrm{nice}\;\mathrm{computation})$$
I promise that the the next part of the algorithm is as fun as this one.
But, first, an interesting property:
Property 1 : When $a=1$, $\forall \beta\geq b, k_{\beta+1}=z_1k_\beta.$
This property has an interesting consequence that will be useful when one of the computed denominators vanishes. Anyway, to answer the initial problem, we have an algorithm for $a=0$ ($s_1=-d_1$ trivially) and for $a=1$ thanks to Theorem 1 ($s_1=2\frac{k_{b+1}}{k_b}-d_1$.)
Let me sum up those two results in the first two lines of an array $S_{u,v}$ where I choose to focus on the $(3,4)$ entry and where the first line ($u=0$) is filled with $-d_1$ and the second line ($u=1$) is filled with the computed values of $2\frac{k_{v+1}}{k_v}-d_1$ :
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\ \hline 0 & &  &  &2 &2 &2   \\
1&&&-36 &\frac{72}{19}&\frac{936}{17}&\frac{2808}{451}&\frac{22824} { 953}\\
2&&&&\frac{128} {21}&\frac {104} {23}&\frac{61} {13}\\
3&&&&&10
\end{array}$$
Of course, you're not supposed to know the values I chose of $z_i$ ($-4, 3$ and $5$) and $p_i$ ($-3,1,2$ and $6$) to build this array. Also, you should note that I use one of the consequences of Theorem 1 to compute the values of $S_{1,v}$ even if $a\neq 1$, that makes the process so difficult for me to prove.
The main theorem is just what it looks like:
Theorem 2 : When $a\leq b$,$\quad s_1=S_{a,b}$.
with the final ingredient of this exposition :
Definition 2 :
$$
S_{u,v}=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cl}
-d_1 & \mathrm{when}\quad u=0\\
 2\frac{k_{v+1}}{k_v}-d_1 &\mathrm{when}\quad u=1\\
\frac{S_{u-1,v}(S_{u-1,v-1}-S_{u-1,v+1})+S_{u-2,v}(S_{u-1,v+1}-S_{u-1,v}) }{S_{u-1,v-1}-S_{u-1,v}} & \mathrm{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Consider the rational function $R(z) =A(z)/B(z)$ formed by taking the quotient of the monic polynomials of the given degrees $a$ and $b$ whose respective roots $z_i$ and $p_j$ are not yet known.
The logarithmic derivative $L(z)= R'(z)/R(z) =\frac{A'(z)}{A(z)} -\frac{B'(z)}{B(z)} =\sum_i \frac{1}{z- z_i} -\sum_j \frac{1}{z-p_j} $ has the property that the known power-constants  can be expressed as
$ d_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint _C z^n \frac{R'(z)dz}{R(z) }$ where the circle $C$ has large radius. Thus these power-constants are the Laurent coefficients of an expansion of $L(z)$ in powers of $w=1/z$. Integrating once in $z$ term-wise, and exponentiating, we obtain a formal Laurent expansion for $R(z) =A(z)/B(z)$, i.e. a Taylor expansion in $w$.
The problem of finding a computational  algorithm for  reconstructing the numerator and denominator  of $R(z)$ from the  series expansion is equivalent to solving the recurrence equation $ B(z) R(z)= A(z)$ for unknowns polynomials $A$ and $B$.
The computational problem of solving for these two polynomials is  discussed here: Taylor expansion of rational function in disguise
P.S. Note that in your setting the known bounds on the degrees of $A$ and $B$ should in theory make your problem more tractable than is suggested by some of the pessimistic objections appearing in the comments in that link.
However, I also suspect that since the coefficients for $L(z)$ will be most strongly determined by just the   pole of $L(z)$ of smallest norm, the actual computations that determine $A$ and $B$ will in practice often be unstable.

That is indeed the reason why I was looking for an algorithm : having $R$, how to approximate it rationally. Unfortunately,  your references seem to only mention non-deterministic algorithms.
